# Compare API value to a local stored value at each request to API

Tags: objective-c, ios8, compare, afnetworking-2, xcode6.3

OK, total brain freeze. I have a response from the CI Jenkins API. The result contains a successful build number for my project at Jenkins which increments each time a successful build on the Jenkins platform runs.

Now I want my app to check with a request if there is a **new** successful build, and if there is I want inform the user about it. So how can I store the current build number in the app and then compare it to each time I make a request to check the Jenkins build number to compare if the local stored build number is less than the build number on my Jenkins

```
[manager GET:@"http://jenkins.myProject/lastSuccessfulBuild/api/json" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSDictionary *responseDict = responseObject;

    NSInteger repsonsBuildNumber = [responseDict[@"number"] integerValue];

    if ([responseDict[@"result"] integerValue] == BuildStateSuccess && repsonsBuildNumber > self.currentBuildNumber ) {
        NSLog(@"There is a new succesful build at Jenkins");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"There currentBuildNumber is the same as the repsonsBuildNumber");
    }

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

So how can I store the `currentBuildNumber` to compare it to the `repsonsBuildNumber` whit each request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSUserDefaults` is perfect for this. Just use `-(NSInteger)integerForKey:` to get the current build number stored:

```
 NSInteger currentBuildNumber = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"currentBuildNumber"]];
 NSInteger repsonsBuildNumber = [responseDict[@"number"] integerValue];

 if (currentBuildNumber < repsonsBuildNumber) {
     // there is a new build
 }
```

Then to set it, just use

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:repsonsBuildNumber forKey:@"currentBuildNumber"]];
```

Comment: where is it best to update the currentBuildNumber to the responsBuildNumber? Or rather, How do I prevent the currentBuildNumber to be overwritten without the user downloading the latest ipa generated from the latest successful build?

Comment: @Oskariagon in the if statement, just add in the second code snippet, that way it'll only update if there's a new version, and it'll set it to the latest version (at that time). Make sense?

Comment: yeah it works, thanks for the help of clearing that out! Now I can control if the user want's to download the new build at Jenkins or stick with the current build.